# how to create video thumbnail from ffmpeg in xamp php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$ffmpeg = 'C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe';  

//video dir  
$video = 'C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\upload.mp4';  
echo $video ;
//where to save the image  
$image = 'C:\ffmpeg\image\image.jpg';  

//time to take screenshot at  
$interval = 5;  

//screenshot size  pn 
$size = '640x480';  

//ffmpeg command  
//$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i ".$video "-deinterlace -an -ss".$interval". -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y    -s". $size." ". $image." 2>&1";  
$cmd="$ffmpeg -i ".$video." -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 ".$image;
echo $cmd
//$cmd = "$ffmpeg  -i $video -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 150x150 -an myimage.jpg";
exec($cmd);
//$return = '$cmd';  
//print_r($outputData);
?>
```

i want to create thunbnail from video file .  i have correctly configured ffmpeg to xamp
as it shows in phpinfo. my code is running  correctly , there is no error showing .
But video thumb nail is no where  generating.
  Please  provide me the source code . if it is possible . its very urgent

Answer (score 1):

Your path to the video contains spaces, so it must be quoted

Change

```
$video = 'C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\upload.mp4';
```

to

```
$video = '"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\upload.mp4"';
```